# activating "authorization" causes CSS stop working! how solve it?

Tags: asp.net, css, authorization

when i use:

```
<deny users="?"/>
```

in "authorization" tags, CSS stop working for unauthorized visitors. how can i define a exception for css files. i want them to apply to all visitors.

this is my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
        <roleManager enabled="true"/>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="welcome.aspx" defaultUrl="Default.aspx"/>
        </authentication>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

i did edit my web.config to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
        <roleManager enabled="true"/>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="welcome.aspx" defaultUrl="Default.aspx"/>
        </authentication>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
       </system.web>

       <location path="styles">
         <system.web>
          <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
          </authorization>
         </system.web>
      </location>

     <location path="styles/welcome.css">
      <system.web>
       <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
       </authorization>
      </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

and it's working.
thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the location of your CSS to your web.config. You can put it completely at the end, just before the `</configuration>`

```
<location path="css">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
   </location>
```

Of course, change "css" to the real folder of your css file... It is the easiest to put it in a separate folder where all items are public. Just like your images etc.

Comment: i found when i use <location path="css\welcome.css">, <deny users="?"/> line won't apply anymore, and every visitors can reach any pages. i'm testing it on local ISS(MS Visual Studio 2011). is there any change that it authorize windows users as visitors?

Comment: deny users = ? means you exclude authenticated users only. But you want everybody to access your public stuff

Comment: also this allow * will only work for the folder /css so all your other pages go by the default. Just try it...

Comment: i did exactly as you told. please take a look at my edited web.config. still it's not working!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably blocking access to the folder where you store css files.

Try to allow everybody to access your css-folder even if they are not autorized.

Comment: but how? css file is in a folder named "css". how can i make that happen?

Comment: Your changes should work. You could try using Fiddler or another tool to see what response you get when the browser tries to download the css file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Location element to define which part of your site the configuration applies to:

(from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx))

```
<location allowOverride="True|False" path="path" />
```

Comment: it seems it doesn't work. i added <location path="welcome.css" /> but no change at all

Comment: You'd need to give it a path, rather than a filename, IIRC :)